# Hide chat messages based on content

Tags: script, chat

Want to get those *Game of Thrones* spoilers out of your chat? Hate [certain things](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kfVsfOSbJY0)? Automatically hide chat messages based on a blacklist of words.

### Instructions

- **[Download the User script](https://gist.github.com/fredley/6abe0386a58a66c99f2d)**
- Edit `IGNORE_LIST` to the list of things you <strike>hate</strike> would rather not see.
- Install into Chrome by dragging the file onto your extensions page, or with Greasemonkey for Firefox
- Enjoy chatting with none of the things you hate!